# container of packed 2-bit integers

Tags: c++

I need a container class that is similar to `std::vector<bool>` but that contains packed 2-bit integers (instead of 1-bit `bool`).
Does such a class exist somewhere, or do I have to write my own?

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is broken, but `std::bitset` might fit your needs. Just add two to index when iterating over it. `for (...) bool LoBit = bset[i]; bool HiBit = bset[i+1];`

Comment: Not as far as I know: you need to write one yourself. Fortunately, it shouldn't be too hard, given the specification for `bool` is there for you to use as your model.

Comment: I'm not clear...are you looking for a container class, or a 2-bit integer class?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to write a class of your own.

```
struct myStorage
{
   ....
}

vector<myStorage> v;
....
```

if you need memory optimization, just using a byte to store your 2 bit numbers (0..3 values).